background process group of subshell when job control is enabled
I'm trying to understand why a script i wrote works. Specifically this one:
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -m
(
    echo "waiting to be killed..."
    sleep inf
)  &
bg_pid=$!
echo $bg_pid
sleep 5

echo "kill $bg_pid"
kill -- "-$bg_pid"

Note the set -m which enables job control. Without it, if i killed -$bg_pid it would say No such process because Job control is disabled, which means the subshell run in the same process group as the shell. But according to this answer when job control is enabled, all subshells go into their own process groups.
But when i run this script and print the process hierarchy before the kill:
   PPID     PID    PGID     SID TTY        TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
 173828  173890  173890  173890 pts/6     206742 Ss    1000   0:00 -bash
 173890  206740  206740  173890 pts/6     206742 S     1000   0:00  \_ /bin/bash ./test1.sh
 206740  206741  206741  173890 pts/6     206742 S     1000   0:00      \_ /bin/bash ./test1.s
 206741  206743  206741  173890 pts/6     206742 S     1000   0:00      |   \_ sleep inf
 206740  206742  206742  173890 pts/6     206742 S+    1000   0:00      \_ sleep 5

we can see sleep inf which is a subprocess of /bin/bash (206741) is in the same process group (206741) as its parent. can somebody explain why this behavior occurs? does the subshell have job control disabled?

The process group of the main script shell is 206740, the process group of the background subshell is 206741.. What's the problem?

To clarify, a subshell is a copy of the current shell created by ( cmd ) or as part of actions such as command substitution or pipelines. Not all child processes are subshells. sleep is just a child of your shell, not a subshell.

Subshells don't have job control even though their parent has.

i know why parent shell runs in PGID: 206740 and why subshell runs in 206741. but why does subshell sleep command run in 206741 as well? no where i check is this behavior outlined.

Subshell 206741 does not have job control enabled, which is why subshell sleep command run in 206741 as well.

but subshells inherit job control from their parents. i modified the test script to verify this. what's going on?

You just need to run (sleep 1 & fg) to see that subshells don't inherit job control from their parents.
